# Show message only when user clicks on show in Markdown

Tags: markdown, commonmark

I have a huge text message which I want to show only to people who are interested in more details regarding it.
Adding an illustration below

**Initial preview**

[image: Initial preview]

**On expanding the message**

[image: On expanding the message]

Need help achieving this using markdown.

Answer (score 3):

you could do this like this one

```
<details>
<summary> <b>Some title here</b> </summary>
  your long text here
<details>
```

and if you want it opened by default you could add the attribute `open` to the `details` tag like this

```
<details open>
<summary> <b>Some title here</b> </summary>
  your long text here
<details>
```